# How do I add a RSS feed to Google Reader or Feedly?

Tags: rss, google-reader, rss-reader, feedly

I'm trying to configure Google Reader/Feedly to track JavaWorld articles. JavaWorld offers many different [RSS feeds](http://www.javaworld.com/rss/index.html). I'd like to subscribe to **Core Java**, but I cannot find/add this feed to Google Reader.

Comment: you mean the Core Java Q&A feeds? http://i.imgur.com/Ov22vm9.png

Comment: Yes or even the "Featured Articles"...does it matter?

Comment: Each of those links were the feed links - anyway you got your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the Subscribe button

[image: Subscribe button]

Paste in the link to the feed. In your case:

- http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/1390/feed

Click 'Add' to complete the process.

Comment: Sorry, where is the "subscribe button"?  I don't see one in feedly or google reader.

Comment: In the web interface to Google reader there is a Subscribe button in the upper left. I've edited the answer to include an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already chosen Feedly to replace Google Reader, it appears you can still subscribe via Google Reader, and the new feed will show up in Feedly.  You may have to restart your browser to see it.